# Fastest way in JS to detect number of leading zeros

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, performance, hash

I am working on a project where I need to quickly check if there are a certain number of leading zeros in string. I have had success using regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[0]{' + difficulty + '}.+');
if (regex.test(hash))
```

Also with substring and repeat:

```
if (hash.substring(0, difficulty) === '0'.repeat(difficulty))
```

For my specific purpose, speed is the most important element. I must find the fastest way to check if the number of leading zeros matches the difficulty. I have ran benchmark tests on both methods, but the results fluctuate in a way that I cannot tell which one is better. Also, if there is another better method, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple for loop will do it

Comment: You can loop through strings, so you set the `i = 0; i < 4; i++` so 4 is the amount of leading zeros you want to detect

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp - loop using it. Dunno if it will be more efficient, but its simple.

Comment: or just if(str.substr(0, 4) == "0000")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function detect(hash, difficulty) {
    for (var i = 0, b = hash.length; i < b; i ++) {
        if (hash[i] !== '0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i === difficulty;
}
```

Your methods have drawbacks that you construct intermediate objects and do heavy arithmetics (especially with regexp but with substring and full string comparisons as well). This one should be quite fast.

Comment: The variable you declare in for arguments goes to the top ^ (and you should memorize the hash length for better performance).

Comment: @KlaiderKlai I've accepted your suggestions but to be honest it doesn't really matter. `.length` is cached anyway in all modern browsers and putting `var`s inside the loop makes it less readable IMHO.

Comment: @freakish I'm using most recent Firefox and it didn't cache it... Explain me, then.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai That's impossible. I don't use FF personally but none of the performance tests I've seen on the internet confirms that. I think `length` caching is even part of the standard.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (Number(n).toString() !== n){
    console.log("leading 0 detected")
}
```

this may not be the fastest, but simpler than writing a function